# Disabling pointer output in C++ streams?

Tags: c++, iostream

If you hand any pointer to a C++ stream, it's address will be put into the output. (Obviously unless there's a more specific output handler.)

```
void* px = NULL;
const char* ps = "Test";
FooType* pf = ...;
stringstream s;
s << ps << " " << px << " " << pf "\n";
s.str(); // yields, for example: "Test 0 AF120089"
```

This can be a problem, if the user erroneously was trying to actually print the *value* of FooType.

And it is also a problem when mixing wide char and narrow char, because instead of a compiler error, you'll get the address printed:

```
const wchar_t* str = L"Test! (Wide)";
// ...
cout << str << "\n"; // Ooops! Prints address of str.
```

So I was wondering - since I very rarely want to output a pointer value, **would it be possible to disable formatting of pointer values, so that inserting a pointer value into a stream would result in a compiler error?** (Outputting of pointer values could then be easily achieved by using a wrapper type or casting the pointer values to size_t or somesuch.)

**Edit:** In light of [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094309/disabling-pointer-output-in-c-streams/6094357#6094357) (disabling void* output by providing my own void* output operator) I would like to add that it would be nice if this also worked for tools such as Boost.Format, that make implicit use of the output operator defined in the `std` namespace ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives a compilation error in g++ if the second and/or third output to cout is uncommented:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

ostream & operator << ( const ostream &, void * ) {
}


int main() {
    int n = 0;
    cout << 0;
//  cout << &n;
//  cout << (void *) 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm ... this looks OK. The "normal" void* output operator is defined in namespace std, no? So if there's code that uses the one from std, this won't help ... ?

Comment: Kinda works, but formally you are not allowed to overload operators without at least one user defined parameter type.

Comment: @Bo And what do you think ostream is?

Comment: @nbt: The C++ standard is vague as to if things in `std` are "user defined" or not, sometimes it uses the term one way, and sometimes another.

Answer (score 4):

A global template version of `operator<<` seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, T* value) {
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(false);
}

int main() {
    int foo = 5;
    int * bar = &foo;

    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
```

**Edit:** This solution does not work as intended, as the template also captures string literals. You should prefer @Neil's solution.

Comment: Cool, looks like we came up with pretty much the same answer!

Comment: Wouldn't this be restricted to code in the global namespace? It looks like code in other namespaces would find `::std::operator<<` (due to ADL on `std::cout`) but not `::operator<<`

Comment: @MSalters: On [ideone it works](http://ideone.com/MaqNp) even if the call comes from another namespace. But intuitively I would have agreed with you.

Comment: Weird: the associated namespace of `T*` is that of `T`; `int` doesn't have an associated namespace (fundamental type) so `int*` hasn't got one either. We're obviously overlooking something.

Comment: Ah, forgot: the global namespace is the outer namespace of every namespace. And outer namespaces are searched when _no_ match is found in inner namespaces (which means that this `operator<<` is hidden by any `operator<<` in an inner namespace - but [the example](http://ideone.com/MaqNp) has none)

Comment: @MSalters: And ADL would only apply when no match was found in the outer namespace as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cause a compilation error by providing your own overload of ostream's operator <<.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& s, T* p)
{
  char ASSERT_FAILED_CANNOT_OUTPUT_POINTER[sizeof(p) - sizeof(p)];
}

int main()
{
   int x;
   int* p = &x;
   cout << p;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in an edit of my own answer, this does not work as intended, because it also prevents you from printing string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `operator <<` unimplemented for pointers.

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, T* value);
```

**Edit**: Or better to put an invalid typename to get compiler error.

Comment: That would give a linker error, not a compiler one, wouldn't it?